# Is there any way to obtain the XSD type given a Java Type?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm working with JavaTypes and I want to transform a JavaType to XsdType.
I did not found a simple way to do this, and finally created an method that given a JavaType returns the associated XsdType.

Example:

```
toXsdType(String.class.getName()); --> "xsd:string"
```

In order to achieve this, I'm doing an UGLY switch statement.

Is there a clean way to do it, using JAXB or another library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in `TypeInfoSet.getTypeInfo(T type)` which gives you an XML type for the given Java type.

As for the `TypeInfoSet`, you can obtain it via `JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet()`.

So basically the whole process would look like:

- Create an instance of `JAXBContext` with RI, cast it to `JAXBContextImpl`.
- Get a `TypeInfoSet`.
- Get a `NonElement` for your Java type.
- Get the `QName` using `NonElement.getTypeName()`.